# How to manually link React Native new components with expo?

Tags: react-native, expo, fs

Right now I am trying to add sqlite-storage(https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage) and react-native-fs(https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs/) to a project being done in react-native. Both, however, require me to add some lines of code to the ios and android files. Case is, I created this project using expo, and expo doesn't seem to have those files available.

Currently, I am trying to create some sort of offline storage for my app (I think I'll ditch sqlite because it won't be as necessary and just keep the react-native-fs and write the data on JSON).

I have already tried linking and re-installing it many times and it doesn't seem to work, since it keeps returning the "RNFSManager is undefined" error when I use react-native-fs. A few of the people with this problem I found said they had to manually link, but they all had access to those files I don't have (like setting and gradle, things expo doesn't give me direct access to), so I am not sure what I should do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite and FileSystem are both included on expo. 
First you need to add them to your project with:

```
expo install expo-sqlite
expo install expo-file-system
```

Then you only need to import them

```
import { SQLite } from 'expo-sqlite';
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';
```

For more info you can check the expo docs for
[FileSystem](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/)
and
[SQLite](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/sqlite/)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to eject your expo project, so the android and ios folder will be created.
After that, you will be able to add nativecode to your react-native app.

[The expo documentation](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/expokit/eject/) is nicely done, you will have all the infos about the pros and cons of ejecting